# Failed context type: The context `router.push` is marked as required in `withRouter(t)`, but its value is `undefined`

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Modules react-router and react-router both have version 4.2.2
. Following is my react routing .

```
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(createBrowserHistory(), store);
const HeaderWithRouter = withRouter(Header);


    ReactDOM.render(

            <Provider store = {store}>
            <Router history = {history} >
               <section>
                    <HeaderWithRouter/>
                    <Route from = '/' to = '/deals'/>
                    <Route exact path="/deals" component={DealList}/>
                    <Route path = "/deal" component={FormDeal}/>
                    <Route path = "/admin" component={Admin}/>
                    <Route path = "/mandate" component={Mandate}/>
                    <Footer/>
               </section>
          </Router>
          </Provider>
              ,
        document.getElementById('app'));
```

The thing that is not working is `<Route from = '/' to = '/deals'/>`
and i get this warning too - `Failed context type: The context`router.push`is marked as required in`withRouter(t)`, but its value is`undefined`.`